# Identifying golang deadlock. 5 philosophers problem

Tags: go, goroutine

I am getting `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`
on the line `wg.Wait()`
It happens for about ~30% of the runs, the rest are finished with no error. I guess I am using WaitGroup the wrong way, but not sure what am I doing wrong.
Maybe someone can help me identify my bug? Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    numOfPhilosophers = 5
    numOfMeals = 3
    maxEaters = 2
)

var doOnce sync.Once

func main() {
    chopsticks := make([]sync.Mutex, 5)
    permissionChannel := make(chan bool)
    finishEating := make(chan bool)
    go permissionFromHost(permissionChannel,finishEating)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numOfPhilosophers)
    for i:=1 ; i<=numOfPhilosophers ; i++ {
        go eat(i, chopsticks[i-1], chopsticks[i%numOfPhilosophers], &wg, permissionChannel, finishEating)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func eat(philosopherId int, left sync.Mutex, right sync.Mutex, wg *sync.WaitGroup, permissionChannel <-chan bool, finishEatingChannel chan<- bool) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i:=1 ; i<=numOfMeals ; i++ {
        //lock chopsticks in random order
        if RandBool() {
            left.Lock()
            right.Lock()
        } else {
            right.Lock()
            left.Lock()
        }

        fmt.Printf("waiting for permission from host %d\n",philosopherId)
        <-permissionChannel

        fmt.Printf("starting to eat %d (time %d)\n", philosopherId, i)
        fmt.Printf("finish to eat %d (time %d)\n", philosopherId, i)
        //release chopsticks
        left.Unlock()
        right.Unlock()

        //let host know I am done eating
        finishEatingChannel<-true
    }
}

func permissionFromHost(permissionChannel chan<-bool, finishEating <-chan bool) {
    ctr := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-finishEating:
            ctr--
        default:
            if ctr<maxEaters {
                ctr++
                permissionChannel<-true
            }
        }
    }
}

func RandBool() bool {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Intn(2) == 1
}
```

**Edit 1**: I fixed the mutex to be passed by reference. It didn't solve the problem.

**Edit 2**: I tried to use buffered channel `permissionChannel:=make(chan bool, numOfPhilosophers)` which makes it work

**Edit 3**: also @Jaroslaw example makes it work

Comment: There are several errors: 1) You are passing mutexes by value. Pass them by address. 2) Locking mutexes in different order is deadlock-prone

Comment: @BurakSerdar thanks for your comment, but the deadlock is on the wg.Wait() doesn't like it is related to the mutexes. The program thinks not all goroutines called wg.Done().

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in the code. Fix mutexes and the behavior is likely to change.

Comment: Deadlock is not on wg.Wait, that's where it can be detected. It is likely that all the other goroutines are already deadlocked, but the runtime can continue because the main goroutine can still run. When the main goroutine stops at wg.wait(), there are no other running goroutines, and the deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

The `go vet` command says

```
./main.go:26:13: call of eat copies lock value: sync.Mutex
./main.go:26:30: call of eat copies lock value: sync.Mutex
./main.go:31:34: eat passes lock by value: sync.Mutex
./main.go:31:52: eat passes lock by value: sync.Mutex
```

Another problem is that there are times when goroutines (philosophers) get blocked when trying to send an acknowledgement on `finishEatingChannel`, because the goroutine (host) responsible for reading data from this unbuffered channel is busy trying to send a permission. Here is the exact part of code:

```
            if ctr<maxEaters {
                ctr++
                // This goroutine stucks since the last philosopher is not reading from permissionChannel.
                // Philosopher is not reading from this channel at is busy trying to write finishEating channel which is not read by this goroutine.
                // Thus the deadlock happens.
                permissionChannel<-true 
            }
```

Deadlock is 100% reproducible when there is only one philosopher left who needs to eat twice.

Fixed version of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    numOfPhilosophers = 5
    numOfMeals        = 3
    maxEaters         = 2
)

func main() {
    chopsticks := make([]sync.Mutex, 5)
    permissionChannel := make(chan bool)
    finishEating := make(chan bool)
    go permissionFromHost(permissionChannel, finishEating)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numOfPhilosophers)
    for i := 1; i <= numOfPhilosophers; i++ {
        go eat(i, &chopsticks[i-1], &chopsticks[i%numOfPhilosophers], &wg, permissionChannel, finishEating)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func eat(philosopherId int, left *sync.Mutex, right *sync.Mutex, wg *sync.WaitGroup, permissionChannel <-chan bool, finishEatingChannel chan<- bool) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 1; i <= numOfMeals; i++ {
        //lock chopsticks in random order
        if RandBool() {
            left.Lock()
            right.Lock()
        } else {
            right.Lock()
            left.Lock()
        }

        fmt.Printf("waiting for permission from host %d\n", philosopherId)
        <-permissionChannel

        fmt.Printf("starting to eat %d (time %d)\n", philosopherId, i)
        fmt.Printf("finish to eat %d (time %d)\n", philosopherId, i)
        //release chopsticks
        left.Unlock()
        right.Unlock()

        //let host know I am done eating
        finishEatingChannel <- true
    }
}

func permissionFromHost(permissionChannel chan<- bool, finishEating <-chan bool) {
    ctr := 0
    for {
        if ctr < maxEaters {
            select {
            case <-finishEating:
                ctr--
            case permissionChannel <- true:
                ctr++
            }
        } else {
            <-finishEating
            ctr--
        }
    }
}

func RandBool() bool {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return rand.Intn(2) == 1
}
```

Comment: Thank! that works, not sure I understand "the goroutine responsible for reading data from this unbuffered channel is busy trying to send a permission", doesn't it suppose to get back and handle the that channel because it is running in an endless for loop?

Comment: I've extended the answer. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The last goroutine will not exit, it will get blocked in its last iteration when it is writing to the `finishEatingChannel` channel as there are no consumers for it.
The reason there are no consumers for the  `finishEatingChannel` is that the select case in the function `permissionFromHost` is writing to `permissionChannel<-true` but there are no consumers for `permissionChannel` as it is waiting for it to be read so we have a deadlock.

You can make the permissionFromHost channel buffered, it will resolve the issue.

There is also a bug in your code, you are passing mutex by value which is not allowed

Comment: Thanks! that was very insightful